# How to customize AnimatedCrossFade with a flip animation in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to switch between 2 card widgets on a button press. I found AnimatedCrossFade which does exactly the same but the switch animation is a fading one. I want to make a flip animation when it switches. How do I do that?

Comment: Look up `AnimatedSwitcher`, you can specify how you want it to be switched.

Comment: Can you help me with that? A quick example to switch between two widgets?

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
...
AnimatedSwitcher(
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
  transitionBuilder: (child, animation) => SizeTransition(
    sizeFactor: animation.drive(CurveTween(curve: 
       //these intervals might be wrong, but the point is
       //you can differentiate what is transitioning using the key
       child.key == Key("flipped")
         ? Interval(0.5, 1.0)
         : Interval(0.0, 0.0)
    )),
    child: child,
  ),
  child: myState.isButtonFlipped
    ? FlippedWidget(
      key: Key("flipped"),
    )
    : MyButton(
      key: Key("notFlipped"),
    ),
),
```

If you want a different transition, look at the source for `SizeTransition` and see if you can make your own `FlipTransition` in a similar manner that uses `Transform`.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. I am using RotationTransition to rotate the widget. But it is being rotated along the in 2-D. Is there a way to rotate along the z-axis using that?

Comment: There's a Transform widget, but not a transition. So use an Animated builder as the Transition widget, which has a Transform inside.

Comment: Thank you for posting this example of how to use AnimatedSwitcher with a transition.  This crucial info is missing from the Flutter docs.  Thank you!